# How can I run an Apache Zeppelin notebook from another notebook in the same local machine?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I tried

```
%sh
curl -POST 'http://my_ip:8080/api/notebook/job/my_notebook_id'
```

but got an error "can't find the requested URL"

Comment: did u found a solution for it?

Comment: yes, see the solution below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, works like a charm:

```
# get credentials
curl  --data 'userName=user&password=passwd' -c cookies.txt -XPOST http://server:8080/api/login

## run notebook with id 2DMZYRW7W
curl -b cookies.txt -X POST 'http://server:8080/api/notebook/job/2DMZYRW7W'
```